# Python re: if string has one word AND any one of a list of words?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find if a string matches on this rule using a regular expression:

```
list_of_words = ['a', 'boo', 'blah']
if 'foo' in temp_string and any(word in temp_string for word in list_of_words)
```

The reason I want it in a regular expression is that I have hundreds of rules like it and different from it so I want to save them all as patterns in a dict.

The only one I could think of is this but it doesn't seem pretty:

```
re.search(r'foo.*(a|boo|blah)|(a|boo|blah).*foo')
```

Comment: "I want to save them in a dict" doesn't necessarily require you to construct a regex. As long as you have all the data you need to reconstruct the logic, what does it matter how it's stored? `{"whatever": ("foo", ("a", "boo", "blah"))}` is just as valid a dict as ``{"whatever": r'foo.*(a|boo|blah)|(a|boo|blah).*foo'}``

Comment: wouldn't (more or less) `if re.search('foo') and re.search("(a|boo|blah)"):` do what you want?

Comment: I tried, I have 100 different rules and they differ. I can't go in to too much detail about it but storing them as sets of words doesn't work for me. It would get very complicated and and anyone looking at the dictionary not familiar with what each set means (is it an OR or an AND) etc would struggle. A regular expression leaves no room for guessing. 

Maybe I shouldn't have said "rules like it"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes it would, but then I can't store it as one single expression in my dictionary. This rule is one example from many more that I have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can join the array elements using `|` to construct a lookahead assertion regex:

```
>>> list_of_words = ['a', 'boo', 'blah']

>>> reg = re.compile( r'^(?=.*\b(?:' + "|".join(list_of_words) + r')\b).*foo' )

>>> print reg.pattern
^(?=.*\b(?:a|boo|blah)\b).*foo

>>> reg.findall(r'abcd foo blah')
['abcd foo']
```

As you can see we have constructed a regex `^(?=.*\b(?:a|boo|blah)\b).*foo` which asserts presence of one word from `list_of_words` and matches `foo` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain how that pattern works? How is it ignoring the order of the list of words and foo?

Comment: It is not ignoring list of words. Using lookahead it is asserting presence of any of the word from `list_of_words` in the given input. [Read more about look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: I tried looking in to what everything in that regex means but here's what I don't understand:

Why do we need the `^` at the start? Or is it just good practice?

Why do we need the word boundary `\b`?

What does the `(?:` part do? 

Sorry I know I'm asking a lot of questions but I would like to understand why we're doing each step of the regex so I can understand it.

Comment: 1. `^` is not really required here so can be left out. 2. `\b` is for word boundary so that while matching for `foo` we don't match `food`. 3. `(?:..)` is for non-capturing group, this is used for over all efficiency purpose.

Comment: Thank you. 

I was playing around with it and found that when I use a negative lookahead, I had to put in `^` before it else it didn't work. 

For example, to say if string at any stage contains `foo` and doesn't contain `boo` I would have to write: `match_2 = re.search(r'(?=.*\bfoo\b)^(?!.*\bboo\b)', st)` but if I wanted to check if it had both `foo` and `boo` I don't need the `^` so I can do this: `match_2 = re.search(r'(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bboo\b)', st)`